# Distinguishing Gamma-rays and stars from each other in nebulas

Tags: astrophysics, stars, gamma-rays, nebulae

How do you tell the difference between a gamma-ray burst and a star just from a picture of a nebula, in which it cannot flash on and off here and there?

Comment: Well, one way is that it won't be in pictures from the past, and will vanish from pictures in the future. It will also have a different spectrum than a star. GRBs emit mostly gamma rays (hence the name) while stars have very different (roughly thermal) spectra.

Comment: @William, what do you mean by "from a picture of nebula"... [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma-ray_burst) says GRBs are emitted from supernovae, neutron stars, quark stars and black holes.

Comment: What? How does it vanish from pictures in the future?

@CrazyBuddy, I know that, but I heard GRBs go off every .33 seconds in the Crab Nebula, therefore if you see a picture of a Crab or any other nebula, then surely you would think that some of the glowing orbs in the picture aren't stars, and maybe just one is a GRB. It seems logical in my perspective.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[GRBs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_ray_burst) have a spectra far more [Red-shifted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_shift) than that of *a star*.. In fact, GRBs have such an unique spectra that nothing matches with it. Its profile has one or two high peaks of 1/2 seconds during which most of the energies will be emitted.. An ordinary star would be bright in optical wavelength... But, doesn't have any crazy peaks & hence won't be extremely red-shifted (Otherwise, we won't be able to see them) A GRB's redshift can be measured only with the afterglow when the initial gamma ray flare would be over. Also, Crab nebula **doesn't host** GRB phenomenon... It only flares up because of some abnormal neutron star spin-down or magnetic disturbances. And we're able to catch the ultra high energy gamma ray photons from Crab *only because* it's so nearer to us than any GRB you can name of... GRBs are always highly red-shifted extra-galactic explosions.

Answer (score 1):

Observations are not made with a single photograph frame, they're made over longer periods of time (for example, a friend takes observations of [Herbig stars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbig_Ae/Be_star) over 2 minute periods in the [J-band](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J_band) with [Gemini North](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemini_Observatory)). The emissions from stars range from UV to IR (depending on your opinion, it could also range from IR to UV ;) ), these emissions are *continuous* (though periodic variances can be observed, hence the term ["variable stars"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_star), but we'll ignore that class for now), so taking an observation now should give you (roughly) the same data any time later

[Gamma-ray bursts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma-ray_burst), on the other  hand, last for no more than 10 seconds (this type are called long-duration GRBs with short-duration GRBs taking less than 2 seconds) and then disappear (quiescence)--there are a class of objects called [soft-gamma repeaters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_gamma_repeater) (SGR) that periodically (albeit irregularly) emit gamma-ray bursts, but not at the same flux as traditional GRBs, so they're not quite the same thing<sup>1</sup>. Below is an example of a long-duration GRB light curve which shows how quick/efficient observations of GRBs need to be,

[image]
([source](http://gammaray.msfc.nasa.gov/batse/grb/lightcurve/))

Side note: The above is actually the last GRB detected by the BATSE detector on the [Compton Gamma-ray observatory (CGRO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_Gamma_Ray_Observatory) before it went offline in 2000.

The next obvious difference is the energies of the photons received. Gamma ray bursts have huge fluxes in, well, the gamma-ray regime:
[image]
([source](http://www.personal.psu.edu/puv2/))

A [study done a few years ago](http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.0645) (arXiv preprint) using the [Fermi space telescope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_Gamma-ray_Space_Telescope) looked at a few [T-Tauri stars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T_Tauri_star). The results (found in Table 2 of the paper) show fluxes on the order of $10^{-11}\,{\rm erg/cm^2/s}$, compared to the above $\sim10^{-5}\,{\rm erg/cm^2/s}$ for a GRB. So while gamma-ray emissions may be found in stars (particularly young ones)<sup>2</sup>, they're not at the same energy or duration as GRBs.

## TL;DR:

We can tell the difference between a star and a gamma-ray burst based mostly on the energy of the signal received, but also the duration of the signal.

---

<sup>1 This is probably where your confusion of the Crab nebula being a GRB, it's often considered an SGR.</sup>

<sup>2 It's actually believed that the gamma-ray signal in the T-Tauri stars stem from the acceleration of protons or electrons at [magnetic reconnection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_reconnection) events in the [accretion disc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accretion_disc), rather than from the star itself, so this statement might be misleading.</sup>